# How to get the value of a key in a JSON?

Tags: json, regex, linux, bash, grep

I have a JSON body. I would like to obtain the value of "access_token". I would like to use grep in bash. The grep I used doesn't not work.

I tried the following but it provides me a blank result.

```
HTTP_BODY=$(echo $HTTP_RESPONSE | grep ^"access_token":" ","experies_in$ )
```

I want only to obtain the access_token value, i.e.:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE4M0UwQTFEQTY1MzE0NkZENUQxOTFDMzRDNTQ0RDJDODYyMzMzMzkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJxRDRLSGFaVEZHX1YwWkhEVEZSTkxJWWpNemsifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTkzMTYzNTYsImV4cCI6MTU1OTMxOTk1NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jaW5jaHktbnByLmNsb3VkLnJlcy5ibmdmLmxvY2FsL2NpbmNoeXNzbyIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2NpbmNoeS1ucHIuY2xvdWQucmVzLmJuZ2YubG9jYWwvY2luY2h5c3NvL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImpzX2FwaSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhcGkiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU5MzE2MzU2LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInByb2ZpbGUiOiJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBjaW5jaHkuY28iLCJyb2xlIjoiQ2luY2h5IFVzZXIgQWNjb3VudCIsImlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJqc19hcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbImN1c3RvbSJdfQ.O0--cahxPKlwHp-7fP0CMgSJTaXleupH32x7vVoxe8THVdeRIgyuZoKWPAK9p10PMO9a5Mi3N0t1Nqut5-dUS7lmeUfNKe25K1got9de7ghQ56QQXnL2SWd6g4I8Zi1R9fZsln7bZCIJvnG3_wIWHKGHBco9jEvKtO3AdYF4T9LAbdpT51SDzKPhX16BPc0Do6KfNImQpPQdK4fP3-JqxD4sOBldUg-g3aau2F_DmapEd0p5hTI4qeKgORnXJ3NadwWscQREGWVXhIRu_BF_cmEoIfPNyJI7D_L7EWn8XcFa2Gu-8khQ-WDpVUcpyidF_VHYRkMtYwpJ2dcYUaLILQ
```

---

Input:

```
HTTP_RESPONSE="{"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE4M0UwQTFEQTY1MzE0NkZENUQxOTFDMzRDNTQ0RDJDODYyMzMzMzkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJxRDRLSGFaVEZHX1YwWkhEVEZSTkxJWWpNemsifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTkzMTYzNTYsImV4cCI6MTU1OTMxOTk1NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jaW5jaHktbnByLmNsb3VkLnJlcy5ibmdmLmxvY2FsL2NpbmNoeXNzbyIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2NpbmNoeS1ucHIuY2xvdWQucmVzLmJuZ2YubG9jYWwvY2luY2h5c3NvL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImpzX2FwaSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhcGkiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU5MzE2MzU2LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInByb2ZpbGUiOiJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBjaW5jaHkuY28iLCJyb2xlIjoiQ2luY2h5IFVzZXIgQWNjb3VudCIsImlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJqc19hcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbImN1c3RvbSJdfQ.O0--cahxPKlwHp-7fP0CMgSJTaXleupH32x7vVoxe8THVdeRIgyuZoKWPAK9p10PMO9a5Mi3N0t1Nqut5-dUS7lmeUfNKe25K1got9de7ghQ56QQXnL2SWd6g4I8Zi1R9fZsln7bZCIJvnG3_wIWHKGHBco9jEvKtO3AdYF4T9LAbdpT51SDzKPhX16BPc0Do6KfNImQpPQdK4fP3-JqxD4sOBldUg-g3aau2F_DmapEd0p5hTI4qeKgORnXJ3NadwWscQREGWVXhIRu_BF_cmEoIfPNyJI7D_L7EWn8XcFa2Gu-8khQ-WDpVUcpyidF_VHYRkMtYwpJ2dcYUaLILQ","expires_in":360,"token_type":"Bearer"}"
```

Expected Output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE4M0UwQTFEQTY1MzE0NkZENUQxOTFDMzRDNTQ0RDJDODYyMzMzMzkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJxRDRLSGFaVEZHX1YwWkhEVEZSTkxJWWpNemsifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTkzMTYzNTYsImV4cCI6MTU1OTMxOTk1NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jaW5jaHktbnByLmNsb3VkLnJlcy5ibmdmLmxvY2FsL2NpbmNoeXNzbyIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2NpbmNoeS1ucHIuY2xvdWQucmVzLmJuZ2YubG9jYWwvY2luY2h5c3NvL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImpzX2FwaSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhcGkiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU5MzE2MzU2LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInByb2ZpbGUiOiJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBjaW5jaHkuY28iLCJyb2xlIjoiQ2luY2h5IFVzZXIgQWNjb3VudCIsImlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJqc19hcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbImN1c3RvbSJdfQ.O0--cahxPKlwHp-7fP0CMgSJTaXleupH32x7vVoxe8THVdeRIgyuZoKWPAK9p10PMO9a5Mi3N0t1Nqut5-dUS7lmeUfNKe25K1got9de7ghQ56QQXnL2SWd6g4I8Zi1R9fZsln7bZCIJvnG3_wIWHKGHBco9jEvKtO3AdYF4T9LAbdpT51SDzKPhX16BPc0Do6KfNImQpPQdK4fP3-JqxD4sOBldUg-g3aau2F_DmapEd0p5hTI4qeKgORnXJ3NadwWscQREGWVXhIRu_BF_cmEoIfPNyJI7D_L7EWn8XcFa2Gu-8khQ-WDpVUcpyidF_VHYRkMtYwpJ2dcYUaLILQ
```

Comment: `grep` is not appropriate for parsing JSON.

Comment: BTW, `echo $anything` is buggy; it needs to be `echo "$anything"`, or even better, `printf '%s\n' "$anything"`, to prevent potentially corrupting your values.

Comment: Please don't use regex to parse xml ,xhtml, html, source code or json.

Comment: @thatotherguy, ...I certainly would close it as a duplicate; the OP there is similarly asking for standard UNIX tools. If standard UNIX tools *aren't* fit for the job... well, that's an answer. Moreover, there are answers on that question showing how to use a Python interpreter, which the OP almost certainly has.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I can only use basic UNIX commands. I cannot use a Python interpreter. I.e. sed, awk, or grep

Comment: @codermonkey321: Unfortunately, your system is not suitable for processing JSON.

Comment: @codermonkey321, ...which specific system are you targeting, so we can look into the set of tools available there?

Answer (score 3):

```
jq -r '.access_token' file
```

Output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkE4M0UwQTFEQTY1MzE0NkZENUQxOTFDMzRDNTQ0RDJDODYyMzMzMzkiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ4NXQiOiJxRDRLSGFaVEZHX1YwWkhEVEZSTkxJWWpNemsifQ.eyJuYmYiOjE1NTkzMTYzNTYsImV4cCI6MTU1OTMxOTk1NiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jaW5jaHktbnByLmNsb3VkLnJlcy5ibmdmLmxvY2FsL2NpbmNoeXNzbyIsImF1ZCI6WyJodHRwczovL2NpbmNoeS1ucHIuY2xvdWQucmVzLmJuZ2YubG9jYWwvY2luY2h5c3NvL3Jlc291cmNlcyIsImpzX2FwaSJdLCJjbGllbnRfaWQiOiJhcGkiLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoxNTU5MzE2MzU2LCJpZHAiOiJsb2NhbCIsInByb2ZpbGUiOiJBZG1pbmlzdHJhdG9yIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhZG1pbkBjaW5jaHkuY28iLCJyb2xlIjoiQ2luY2h5IFVzZXIgQWNjb3VudCIsImlkIjoiYWRtaW4iLCJzY29wZSI6WyJqc19hcGkiXSwiYW1yIjpbImN1c3RvbSJdfQ.O0--cahxPKlwHp-7fP0CMgSJTaXleupH32x7vVoxe8THVdeRIgyuZoKWPAK9p10PMO9a5Mi3N0t1Nqut5-dUS7lmeUfNKe25K1got9de7ghQ56QQXnL2SWd6g4I8Zi1R9fZsln7bZCIJvnG3_wIWHKGHBco9jEvKtO3AdYF4T9LAbdpT51SDzKPhX16BPc0Do6KfNImQpPQdK4fP3-JqxD4sOBldUg-g3aau2F_DmapEd0p5hTI4qeKgORnXJ3NadwWscQREGWVXhIRu_BF_cmEoIfPNyJI7D_L7EWn8XcFa2Gu-8khQ-WDpVUcpyidF_VHYRkMtYwpJ2dcYUaLILQ
```

---

See: `man jq`

Comment: I cannot use jq. Only basic linux commands